# How to create an index for already released field in managed package to automatically propagate it to all subscribers on upgrade

Tags: managed-package, query, custom-index

We are receiving bunch of errors from subscribers' orgs where our managed package is installed:
"System.QueryException: Non-selective query against large object type"

After conducting our local investigation, we discovered that problem stems from not having an index created for one of our fields.
The challenge here is that this field has already been included in released major few versions ago.
And according to managed package restrictions we cannot mark already released field as ExternalId to force SF to create index this way.

The question here is: how can we create index for already released field in such a way, that it would be propagated to all subscriber orgs on upgrade to next managed package version.
We are aware about possibility to create index on specific org by opening case in SF support, but we have hundreds of subscriber orgs and doing this for all of them is simply not feasible (as well as every time when new subscriber org is created).

Introducing a new indexed field is also not a good option for us due to the complexity of data migrations between old and new fields, setting up profile permissions etc.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: were you able to resolve this?

Comment: @PhilB Nope. There is no way to do this according to SF support response. So we are creating indexes per subscriber org basis by opening individual case each time in SF support when concrete client is hitting this limit. Also we've added some monitoring for newly created fields in our managed package to make sure whether they need to be indexed or not before actually releasing major version - to sort of avoid running into the same issue again.